# Display the transaction ID from order notes in a custom column on Woocommerce admin Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Based on *"[Display back Order Notes in Admin orders list on WooCommerce 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025066/display-back-order-notes-in-admin-orders-list-on-woocommerce-3-3/49047149#49047149)"* answer code, that adds in a custom column the order notes in a tooltip, I am trying to figure out how to get the correct data from the "Order Notes" where it shows the transaction ID to display it in a custom column in admin orders list.

Because what this linked answer code is displaying a little icon in a column that when you hover over it shows you the last order note.

All i'm wanting to populate in the column is the transaction ID from the order note.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** - You can simply display the transaction ID using the `WC_Order` [`get_transaction_id()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_transaction_id) method like:

```
echo $the_order->get_transaction_id();
```

So your code hooked functions will be:

```
// Add a custom column before "actions" last column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 100 );
function custom_shop_order_column( $columns ){
    $ordered_columns = array();

    foreach( $columns as $key => $column ){
        $ordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( 'order_date' == $key ){
            $ordered_columns['transaction_id'] = __( 'Transaction id', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }

    return $ordered_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 1 );
function custom_shop_order_list_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ( 'transaction_id' === $column ) {
        echo $the_order->get_transaction_id();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  when I put the code in as a snippet, I went to the orders page on the back end and it says "This site is experiencing technical issues" 

When I disable the snippet the orders page works just fine

Comment: @GajeRobarge Sorry, my fault, there was a mistake… The code is now tested and works.

Comment: Alright I did that. its now created the column, but no transaction id's are populating into it at all. The column is just blank

Comment: @GajeRobarge What payment gateway are you using? or what payment gateway plugin?

Comment: The gateway we are using is called Authorize.net AIM

Comment: @GajeRobarge As this a commercial plugin, you should ask them: how to get the transaction ID that is displayed on order admin notes, from the order ID?